# Importing iOS module from pod to nativescript plugin

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, typescript, nativescript

Currently I have ventured into the world of development with NativeScript and a bit with Typescript, but now I have a problem that has been bothering me a lot.

I'm developing a plugin with the help of 'nativescript-plugin-seed'  which makes use of a pod (AudioKit) for audio conversion. My question is the way I should import the 'AudioKit' module to the plugin in order to make use of its functions and then make use of them in an application

I include the code in Swift for the audio conversion that I tested in a Xcode project to verify its correct operation and the template where I suppose the module  should be imported to generate the methods that will be communicated with my application.

Swift Code

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
       do {
           let origin = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "IOS", withExtension: "mp4")
           let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
           let destination = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("test.wav")
           var options = AKConverter.Options();
           options.format = "wav";
           options.sampleRate = 48000;
           options.bitDepth = 16;
           let converter = AKConverter(inputURL: origin!, outputURL: destination, options: options)
        converter.start(completionHandler: { error in
            if(error != nil){
                print("ERROR")
            }else{
                print("CORRECT")
            }
        })
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

}

Plugin Code (my-plugin.ios.ts)

```
import { Common } from './audio-converter.common';
//I suppose the module should be declared here

export class AudioConverter extends Common {
// and used here
}
```

**EDITED

I already use the commands [HERE](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#troubleshooting) but the typing files are never created.  In the same way I read If the pod was written in Swift I have to configure the pod file and the build.xcconfig, however it doesn’t work anyway. I'll comment the steps I'm doing just to verify that I’m not doing something wrong.

1. Create the plugin with git clone 
   https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed and configuring the plugin's name.....
2. Add the podfile

   ```
    pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.0'
    post_install do |installer|
        installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_SWIFT3_OBJC_INFERENCE'] = 'On'
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.0'
          end
        end
      end
   ```
3. Add to build.xcconfig the flag `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES = YES`
4. Executing these commands for create the typing files in /src (-EDITED For create the typing files these commands must used in /demo)

   ```
     TNS_DEBUG_METADATA_PATH="$(pwd)/metadata" tns build ios [--for-device] [--release]
     TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/typings" tns build ios [--for-device] [--release]
   ```
5. In this point I supose that I have to get the files in typing carpet but I don't get them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the POD setup, all the Objective C exposed apis from the library will be available for you to access. If you like to utilise TypeScript Intellisense for the library, then you will have to generate the typings first.

[Here](https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#troubleshooting) you will find the docs on generating typings. Once it's generated you will have to import them in your `reference.d.ts`.

If you are not already familiar with marshalling Objective C to JS / TS, then you might want to start [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview).

Comment: There is a way of just use javascript for the creation of the plugin? Thank you for the answer I will check the docs

Comment: Yes, you can use JavaScript to build the plugin, TypeScript & generating typings for native library are always optional steps but recommended. You don't have to generate typings if you are not planning to use TypeScript.

Comment: I edited  the answer finding another problem creating the typing scripts

Comment: Typings will be generated only for the apis & methods those are exposed to Objective C. Do you have repo for this plugin?

Comment: Yes, the repo is https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit, now I realized that I had to execute the commands (number 4) in the demo (nativescript project). Actually I already get the typing files but now my problem is when I try to call the methods in the ios.ts file. The typing files that I get does not have the same structure compared with the swift files. 
I need AKConverter class  with an constructor with 3 parameters, but in the d.ts file is just declared the default constructor. In this cases what I need to do?

Comment: You have to refer to the Objective C examples not swift ones. Unfortunately the pod repo doesn't talk much about using it with Objective C.

Comment: I follow this steps in order to use swift classes (https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/Use-Native-iOS-Libraries#apis-written-in-swift) 
But the class that I need is not full converted to typescript. Do I need to declare manually all the missing methods, and properties?